# Why does the combustion of graphite have a positive Delta S?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, entropy

> The following reaction is exothermic and entropically favorable:
>
> $$\ce{C (s) + O2 (g) -> CO2 (g)}$$
>
> My question: Why is this reaction entropically favorable?

Clearly there are more ways to arrange $\ce{C (s)}$ and $\ce{O2 (g)}$ in a container than $\ce{CO2}$.

Sure, the $\ce{CO2}$ has degrees of freedom in it's vibrations, but these shouldn't play a role in determining the entropy of the reaction since the reaction is completely unaffected by the type of vibration $\ce{CO2}$ is doing.

Comment: Have you got the actual number for delta S?

Comment: @Karl +2.9 J K–1

Comment: There is _only one_ way to arrange С (s).

Comment: It seems that the gaseous state of CO2 is not considered in your question and in the above comment. As by @Ivan Neretin comment, do not expect, not to say clearly, more entropy in C than in CO2.

Comment: @IvanNeretin  "There is *only one* way to arrange C (s)."  Nope, that's only true at absolute zero.  I.e., if there really were just one way to arrange C(s) at, say, room temperature, then the absolute entropy of C(s) at room temp would be zero, which is clearly not the case.  Rather, at non-zero temperatures, C(s) has access to a host of different sets of vibrational states, each of which counts as a different arrangement, giving C(s) a non-zero entropy.

Comment: @dljs  "the reaction is completely unaffected by the type of vibration $\ce{CO2}$ is doing."  As you hopefully understood from Buck Thorne's answer, this is absolutely *not* the case.  $\Delta S$ for any reaction is $S_{products} - S_{reactants}$, so the entropies of both the reactants and products must be accounted for, regardless of whether their entropies come from translational, rotational, or vibrational sources (or any other sources that change during the reaction).

Comment: @theorist Yes! This is precisely where I'm confused. I don't understand at a molecular level why the vibrational entropy dictates anything about the reaction spontaneity. Translational entropy makes sense in affecting the reaction (in my mind), but vibrational and rotational do not. Translational entropy gives us the chances that 2 chemical species will be close enough to react, so the translational entropy should play a big role. Vibrational not so much (in my mind at least). I'm about the post a (bountied?) question on Physics Stack Exchange explaining my (flawed) mental model.

Comment: @djis  "close enough to react" would affect the kinetics, not the thermodynamics.  Entropy is a difficult concept. But, very simply put, the entropy is a statistical phenomenon: it is  proportional to the log of the number of possible macroscopically indistinguishable arrangements associated with a given state.  So if you allow a state more possible arrangements, regardless of whether those arrangments are translational, vibrational, or rotational, you increase its probability of occurrence, and thus its entropy.

Comment: @theorist I know I was exaggerating more than a little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of possible explanations for the entropy difference, which can be computed based on [standard free energies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Gibbs_free_energy_of_formation) and [enthalpies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_enthalpy_of_formation) of formation as $\pu{3.0 J/molK}$. First, it could be that the entropy change is so small ($TΔS^∘<\pu{1 kJ}$, compare this to $ΔH^∘=\pu{−393.5kJ/mol}$) and measurement too imprecise for this difference to be significant.

However, an alternate conclusion can be drawn from basic expressions for the translational and rotational entropy of a linear molecule in a gas, as derived from statistical mechanics:

$$\begin{align} S_{\text{rot}}/R &\propto \log{\left( I\right)} \\ S_{\text{trans}}/R &\propto 1.5\log{\left( m\right)}\end{align}$$

where m and I are respectively the mass and moment of intertia of the molecule. The moment of intertia of $\ce{CO2}$ is roughly 4 times that of  $\ce{O2}$, therefore the above two contributions suggest that the molar entropy of $\ce{CO2}$ should be about $\pu{15.5 J/molK}$ greater than that of $\ce{O2}$.

Finally, note that vibrational contributions to the entropy of the gases are expected to be negligible based on basic statistical mechanical expressions. Vibrations in graphite contain softer contributions and therefore vibrations would be expected to contribute more to the entropy of the solid than to that of either gas. [NIST](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C7782425&Type=SS) provides a value of $\approx \pu{5.5 J/molK}$ for the standard entropy of graphite. This doesn't entirely account for the small value of $\Delta_r S^\circ =\pu{3.0 J/molK}$ based on enthalpies and free energies of formation, but brings the estimate a little closer, to $\Delta_r S^\circ \approx \pu{10 J/molK}$.